# scala: Retrieve arguments used to construct class instance in an inheritable way?

Tags: scala, reflection

in scala, i have a situation where a base class/trait is extended by very many child classes. i'm going to be serializing an instance of a child class (for the purpose of reconstructing it later) by getting the name of the class and the arguments used to instantiate the class. it's easy to get the name of the class instance using reflection but i'm not sure how to get the arguments of the instance in a way that doesn't require me to write code in every child class. this needs to also work for arguments called by name. it seems tricky because every child class might have a completely different number and type of constructor arguments:

```
abstract class Base {
  // ideally implements some way of finding out the arguments used to construct this object
  def getArgs = {...}
}

class ChildA() // args would be a 0-tuple

class ChildB(arg1: Int) // getArgs would be a 1-tuple of arg1

class ChildC(arg1: Double, arg2: Boolean) // args would be a 2-tuple of (arg1, arg2)

// etc...
```

what i want to avoid is having each class implementing a method like "getArgs" and just returning a tuple duplicating the arguments from the constructor. any way to do this?

i realize an alternative approach is to have some sort of interceptor for object creation, but i couldn't figure out how to do that without having to write boilerplate code for every child class as well.

edit: the case class approach is elegant but in my situation is not suitable because we must be able to allow concrete child classes to extend other concrete child classes.

Answer (score 9):

If your goal is to avoid writing code in each child class to capture the arguments and all child classes are in a flat hierarchy, directly inheriting from `Base` and not from each other, you should consider declaring them as `case class`es instead. They would then automatically extend [`Product`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Product) and you could use and `productIterator` to e.g. save all args to an `Array[Any]` (I'm using `Array` because that's what's needed when you reflectively call the constructor of these classes later):

```
scala> def toArray(p: Product) = p.productIterator.toArray
toArray: (p: Product)Array[Any]

scala> case class ChildA()
defined class ChildA

scala> toArray(ChildA())
res0: Array[Any] = Array()

scala> case class ChildB(arg1: Int)
defined class ChildB

scala> toArray(ChildB(42))
res1: Array[Any] = Array(42)
```

If you want `toArray` to only accept subclasses of `Base`, then declare its parameter as `Product with Base`.

Comment: @jean-philippe unfortunately some child classes extend other child classes. does that break this scheme? it seems that case class inheritance has been deprecated.

Comment: @Heinrich Indeed, this breaks this technique, unfortunately. (That's why I wrote “if [...] child classes are in a flat hierarchy”.)

Comment: @Heinrich The hierarchy doesn't need to be completely flat, but non-leaf classes *must not* be case classes.  This solution could still work for you if the non-leaf classes could be abstract (i.e. you never instantiate them directly).

Comment: @Heinrich @Aaron's right. But remember that the values returned by `productIterator` would not include `val`s from the abstract superclasses.

Comment: @jean-philippe @aaron thanks - this is certainly a good approach but in my particular case our abstraction must allow concrete child classes to inherit other concrete child classes. it seems like there ought to be a different approach, possibly through serialization...

Comment: Yeah, this is pretty much what I suggested on the mailing list.  Also note the oft-repeated dictum, "Every class should be either abstract or final."